# Erasing Mac HD and keeping Parallels

Tags: macos, partition, disk-format

If I erase my Sierra OS startup disk, will it erase the Parallels partition too? I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If by *Parallels partition* you mean:

- the Parallels Virtual Machine (or .pvm file) *usually* located within the Documents > Parallels folder, **then yes this will be deleted**.
- your running Parallels from a Bootcamp partition, then as long as you're not erasing the Bootcamp partition (i.e. you're only erasing the macOS partition and not the entire drive), **then no this will not be deleted**.
- something else, then please clarify your question.